# Can Xcode 6 and Xcode 5 coexist on the same computer?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode6

I currently have and use Xcode 5, and while I'd like to experiment with Xcode 6, I don't want to use it for production. Can I have both of them installed on the same computer without them conflicting with each other? I couldn't find anything on this on the download page for Xcode 6.

Comment: Keep in mind you might have issues with Xcode Server, check [documentation](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2014/xcode_6_beta_ie8g3n/xcode_6_beta_release_notes.pdf) `Known Issues in Xcode 6 Beta` section for details.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I have them installed side by side right now and I have not encountered any problems with this arrangement.  While I obviously haven't had Xcode 6 for very long, I have done the same thing with several previous Xcode beta releases as well and I have no reason to believe this release would be different.

EDIT: You can use `xcode-select` to switch between the different versions of the command line tools.  From the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html):

> When multiple Xcode applications are installed on a system (e.g. /Applications/Xcode.app,  containing
>          the  latest  Xcode,  and  /Applications/Xcode-DP.app containing a developer preview) use xcode-select
>          --switch path/to/Xcode.app to specify the Xcode that you wish  to  use  for  command  line  developer
>          tools.

Comment: Any ideas on why xcode 6 (when clicked) has its bounce animation, running for 20secondes, and then doesn't launch ? I'm running on 10.9.3

Comment: same for me, can't get it to start

Comment: When running on 10.9.3, it's worth noting there's no immediately noticeable difference in the UI between 5.1 and 6-Beta.

Comment: @user1147981: have you find a way to launch xcode-beta? because I run the same issue :(

Comment: xCode 6 just hangs for a minute or so on the first launch. After that is starts fine. But I'm experiencing a lot of crashes while using Playground.

Comment: It can't take a while to load, if having problems, go to finder, right click and select open app. It will take a while, until it will prompt if you want to open, then another while to open the disclosure or legal terms. Hope it helps.

Comment: @mts See my edit above.  There should be no problem using the command line tools.

Comment: user1147981 - Mine bounced for 2 minutes before asking if I wanted to allow it to open, then it bounced awhile longer and had me accept the user agreement, then it started installing components, then a pinwheel for awhile, then it finally started (meaning nothing happened as it didn't have a previous project selected to open automtically).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I use `sudo XCode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app` but it still took me to XCode 6 beta. Any workaround?

Comment: @newguy What exactly do you mean when you say it "took you to XCode 6 beta"?  What command line tool(s) were you trying to use?

Comment: @EthanHolshouser I use terminal and typed in `open blabla.xcworkspace`

Comment: @newguy `xcode-select` changes the version of Xcode that will be used for the command line tools (such as `xcodebuild`) but as far as I know it does not change the default application for file extensions associated with Xcode (including .xcworkspace).  There are a number of ways to do that, but this is probably the simplest: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2573/os_x_how_to_change_default_application_to_open_file_type/

Comment: Hi All. Just as everyone knows already, Apple released the final version of Xcode 6 yesterday (September 18). Can I still have xcode 5 and xcode 6 together? Could someone please confirm this. Because in Mac app store, the Xcode app asks me to update to new version. Please note that it's an update. Will it replace my Xcode 5?

Answer (score 17):

The answer is YES

Where to download Xcode 6 beta

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/
2. Select [View on the iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
3. Sign in with your Apple Developer ID
4. In the top left, select iOS 8 Beta
5. Scroll down and search for **Xcode 6 beta**

The requirement for Xcode 6 is OS X Mavericks 10.9.3

It will install into /Applications folder with the name **Xcode6-Beta**, so it won't hurt your current Xcode

Comment: @Chandru I'm having both Xcode 5 and 6 on my Macbook and I have only 4GB :)

Comment: Just my 2 cents worth - to bypass the mac app store for downloads this link will take you direct to all dev tool downloads from apple. https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Answer (score 13):

They can both coexist without any problems. You can set version that command line tools use with:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app
```

Xcode 6 works on 10.9 too.

Comment: It's worth noting that it only works on OS X 10.9.3 or greater (not all versions of 10.9)

Answer (score 13):

As said before - XCode 5 and 6 can coexist together.
Just want to add that you can switch between the different versions of the command line tools using the GUI also: open **XCode** -> **Preferences** -> **Locations**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My Xcode 5 icon in the dock turned into a big question mark, as it appears to have been deleted with the install of Yosemite. Further, If I try to re-download it from the app store, it says my version of OS X is 'too new' and refuses to allow me to download. Next I downloaded Xcode 5.1.1 from the developer downloads, which finally allowed me to install it. They are both happily coexisting now on Yosemite.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running OS X 10.9.3 and have XCode 5.1.1 installed. Today I installed the XCode 6 beta and it went without problems. Now I have a `XCode` and a `Xcode6-Beta` app.

Comment: where did you download it ?

Comment: @LenaBru From the Mac Developer page. I believe you need to be enrolled in their paid program to download the beta.

Comment: I am enrolled... i am an ios developer in the company, i have company account for that... where do i download ?

Comment: i m a registered developer(paid account)... but the ios 8 link is disabled on my account.. can u suggest me something?

Comment: @harshitgupta i think that you have to accept latest Program License Agreement. do you see a nice asking you to do that on https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have two Xcode on system but it is advised to keep latest one. While installing Xcode 6 there will be prompt **'Xcode already exists. Replace/Keep it ?**'

Go with **create a new copy of Xcode.** This will install Xcode 6 on your system. The newly installed Xcode will be renamed as **'Xcode 6'**. I'm using Xcode 5.1 and Xcode 6 on my system and there seems to be no issue.

[image: Screenshot for issue]

Comment: Thanks for this. This prompt for "replace/keep" was when installing from the App Store?

Comment: No. You have to use the direct download: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154472/will-the-mas-prompt-me-to-keep-my-xcode-5

Comment: @Yar : Nope when you download an 'dmg' file format. After that installing application 'Replace/Keep' pop-up arises.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to @Ray Richards answer ;) - You can install Xcode 5.1.1 from the following link https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode#

This should allow you to run 5.1.1 and 6 on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can have two separate version on same mac

1. Xcode 6 on the Mac App Store will replace the existing Xcode installation. 
   Only the Xcode betas install separately (by default)
2. Only downloading Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and doing the install manually (by copying Xcode from the DMG to /Applications) will prompt you to replace or keep both.

Select the keep both option when prompt.