# Compatibility of Xcode 5 with Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode6, ios8

Apple has now announced Xcode 6 (and iOS 8). I currently have Mavericks on my Mac (and am not planning to upgrade to Yosemite yet), and am wondering if I can download the Xcode 6 dev preview, while still maintaining my current version of Xcode 5. This is so that I can use the new Xcode 6 features, while still being able to work on, and upload, my current applications. Is that possible?

Also, if I update my phone to iOS 8 Beta, will I be able to run apps from Xcode 5, or only Xcode 6?

Answers would be hugely appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: You need Yosemite for Xcode 6.

Comment: @Kets, it's not true, i've installed Xcode6 in Mavericks, it works like a charm.

Comment: Oh great, going to install it!

Comment: Duplicate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005297/can-xcode-6-and-xcode-5-coexist-on-the-same-computer

Comment: Xcode6 can be installed in Mavericks but the OS version should be 10.9.3 Minimum

Answer (score 2):

Even I use Mavericks, I installed Xcode 6. In order to be sure about my maintenance projects, I've also downloaded Xcode5.1.1 from Apple developer portal, copied it into my Desktop, renamed it as XCode 5.1.1 and then moved it to my applications folder.

I have both versions at the moment without any issues and can also select the version of Xcode while opening an existing Xcode project by using open with menu feature.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 6 Beta Release Notes**

> Xcode 6 Beta requires a Mac running OS X version 10.9.3 (or later) or 10.10.

I think its possible that you can do all things you was able to do with Xcode 5 but I will tell you when my xcode 6 download is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You may install XCode 6 Beta on OS X 10.9.3, and I think that you'll need XCode 6 in order to run iOS8 apps.

One thing that you didn't ask, but that you should keep in mind (as you mentioned your phone):

> Devices updated to iOS 8 beta can not be restored to earlier versions
>   of iOS.

Comment: That's not true, I was able to downgrade fine:
http://www.iclarified.com/41285/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-8-beta-to-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

i've installed Xcode6 in Mavericks and iOS simulator crash with message : **Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.** :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can download the preview of Xcode 6 and use your existing installed Xcode 5 side by side without affecting anything you're doing. Just make sure if you click on a project file that you open it in the correct version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Download xcode dmg file from Apple's developer site. Install it in a different location other than the Applications folder. There you go !!

Comment: Or just rename your current XCode app to XCode5. That way both can be in the Applications folder.