# What happens to my project when updating from xCode 5.1 to xCode6?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode6

I'm currently using xCode 5.1 and Objective-C to learn how to make apps and I'm wondering what would happen to my projects if I update from 5.1 to 6. Will my projects still run or will I have to code everything in Swift?

Comment: xcode 6 supports both objective-c and swift. Real difference is that to install xcode 6.1 with ios 8.1 you should upgrade to Mavericks, if you have not yet. In mavericks you will loose ios 6 simulators support.

Answer (score 1):

Your projects should still run if they were running in previous versions. What will most likely happen is that you will be bombarded by warnings and alerts about deprecated code and syntax. You're going to get a lot of them with an upgrade that big.

For the most part, XCode should tell you exactly what needs to be upgraded. It shouldn't change any of your code. But it's always good practice to back up your project.

Good luck!

See also : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005402/4329655