# Xcode 7 & iOS 7 simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode7

Ive upgraded the version of Xcode to 7 (Release version).

1. Is it possible to have Xcode 7 and Xcode 6 installed side by side?
2. I need to support users on the iOS 7.0 platform but for testing I do not have extra devices with me with iOS 7.0 installed. If the answer to the previous question is NO, is there a way to install iOS 7.0 simulators in Xcode 7
3. Follow up question: If I open a project in Xcode 7 and then open it Xcode 6 will there be any errors in the project files/storyboards?

Comment: can you make your question more clear,do you installed xcode latest version?In which version you done your project?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the latest version of Xcode. It does not have iOS 7.0 simulators. Was wondering how I could get hold of it. One way I could think of was installing Xcode 6.x side by side with Xcode 7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple copies of Xcode.app installed on the same computer and switch between them.  You may run into issues if you try to use both at the same time, but as long as you quit one before using the other, you should be fine.

There is no way to install the iOS 7.0 Simulator with Xcode 7.0.  The iOS 7.0 Simulator Runtime is not supported on Yosemite and newer host OS versions, and Xcode 7.0 is only supported on Yosemite and later.  You will need to use a Mavericks host OS in order to use the iOS 7.0 Simulator Runtime.  If you would be satisfied with the iOS 7.1 Simulator Runtime, that is still supported on Yosemite (but not El Capitan) when using Xcode 6.x (but not Xcode 7.0).

In regards to opening your project in different Xcode versions, there shouldn't be any problems like that.

Comment: That helped me understand it better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your first question i think this link can be help full,please check 
[Can Xcode 6 and Xcode 5 coexist on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005297/can-xcode-6-and-xcode-5-coexist-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: Ive seen the link you've mentioned. But wouldn't want to try it out for various reasons. So would like to know if anyone has actually tried it out and has information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have xCode 6.4 http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg and xCode 7 side by side, just download and install "xCode 2"

Comment: Where do I do the renaming to Xcode 2? Also, does opening the solution in Xcode 7 and then in Xcode 6.4 cause any problems?

Comment: i dont remember, in installation process